# How to customize flutter clean calendar package dates with different colors

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

[flutter_clean_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_clean_calendar)

`final Data = { DateTime(2020, 10, 10): [{'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true, 'color':'red'},], DateTime(2020, 10, 11): [{'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': false, 'color':'white'},], DateTime(2020, 10, 12): [{'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true, 'color':'blue'},], };`

Something similar to this. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Thank God. I got it. Problem Solved perfectly.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how did you solve this issue? I'm facing same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Exactly what I want. I was able to add any color to dates and other dynamics.

Comment: And what about different color of cells borders?